# Get input parameter value for gridview delete (enable)

Tags: vb.net, gridview, messagebox

I've been stuck on a message box problem most of the day.  I've populated a gridview with values.  I've enabled Delete on the gridview and I have been successfully deleting through my stored procedure defined in the GridView Configurations (yay!).  The problem that I am having is the user wants a MessageBox to appear after a row is deleted to let them know that the delete was successful and have a value from that particular row to appear in the message box - i.e. "Record ABC was successfully deleted!".  No matter where I put the code, I can't get the index of the row that was/is/will be deleted.  I attempted to put the code in SelectedIndexChanged, SelectedIndexChanging, RowDeleting, RowDataBound.

Here is my code.  It's very simple, and it is quite possible that I'm missing something, as I am new to VB.net and ASP.net.

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim CouponID As String

i = gvECouponEditor.SelectedIndex

CouponID = gvECouponEditor.Rows(i).Cells(1).Text.ToString()

Dim Answer As MsgBoxResult = MsgBox("You have successfully deleted the ECoupon = " + CouponID, MsgBoxStyle.MsgBoxSetForeground, "Delete Successful!")
```

When I use this code in SelectedIndexChanged(ing), it never touches it.  When I use it anywhere else, it tells me that the index is out of bounds because it is = -1.  Can anyone help me get the row index or the input parameter that I use for my stored procedure (only defined in ASP.net) so that I know which row has the "Delete" link pressed?  I would appreciate any help that you can provide.

Thank you.

Comment: @Brad.  I have tried calling the RowDeleting event - it gave me an error because my index = -1.  Is that what you mean by "hook this event"?  I did all of my "coding" using the GridView Configure Data Source Task, so everything is in ASP.net.

Comment: @Brad.  That was exactly what I needed.  Thank you!  I tried to be thorough in my research before I posted my question, but I completely missed that documentation.  The RowDeleting event allowed me to use e.RowIndex and display my value.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Brad - I've just learned about marking answers as "My answer".  If you add your comment as an answer, I'm happy to mark it as "My Answer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [RowDeleting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdeleting.aspx) event documentation shows an example that sounds a lot like what you're trying to do. In fact, you need to even do less than that example. You should assign an event handler to your grid's `RowDeleting` event and then in the event handler method display a simple Hello, World message.